# is it possible to handle routes without react-router-dom in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom

Actually in my application there are only two screen (ex: home and details) screen. For this we can use react-router-dom library and we can handle. After adding i can see bundle size increase 30 kb.
When i think about performance 30 kb is look like big. is there any way to handle routes without react-router-dom in best way and performance considered as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is YES, you may refer to this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/you-might-not-need-react-router-38673620f3d/), or simply google `light solution`, `react route`,

Comment: Look this up, https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/you-might-not-need-react-router-38673620f3d/